# How can I help LaTeX with the linebreak?

Tags: url

How can I help LaTeX with the linebreak?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{url} 
\begin{document}

I hace a book\footnote{\url{http://www.mazon.de/product/publikationen/hochschulschriften/standard-for-die-exakt-calculation-uncollered-uninfinite-word-finding-smaschinen-28-3-2014.html}}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can add the option `hyphens` to the `url` package.

Comment: And [welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)